# customer login using telephone instead of email

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I am new to Magento and I have few questions, is it possible to change the field email address to telephone in the Sign in form, so that the system authenticates the user based on correct value of the telephone and password ? if it is possible how can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the translation everywhere and kill the email validation everywhere. Should work.

- [Translation can be changed while creating your own local.csv](http://www.magenmarket.com/news-and-blog/how-to-create-custom-language-translation-csv-file-for-your-module-in-magento.html)
- Email validation needs to be killed on client and server side.
- Client side: Search through all your templates for `validate-email` and remove if necessary
- Server side: Rewrite Customer and change `\Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::validate`

Comment: what about if I want to keep both email and telephone fields, because email can be used to sign up for newsletter subscription, is there any way I can keep the email but not show it up in the sign in form, and just use the email and telephone instead...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the telephone number, you need the user to register with both, you can do it, for example by [adding the address to the registering form](https://www.kerstner.at/en/2014/08/enable-address-fields-in-magento-customer-registration-form/)

Then you can have either your own login form which only accepts the telephone number or just implement a second check to check against the phone number.

I'm doing a second check in [my PBKDF2 module][2] instead of changing the password, you can login the user.

The problem is, I can't find any event which can be used for this, so you have to rewrite a lot...

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe I think you would come a long way by checking Diglin's module for using user name instead of email. Either you can refactor the module to use phone field (instead of user) or you'll find inspiration on how to make your own, based on phone number field.

For the record, I was succesful in using this module on a client case to allow login by user name.

https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_Username

Good luck :)